# commit.template not honored when amending?

Tags: git

I have a `~/.commitmessage` file that looks like this:

```
# If applied, this commit will...
```

I've ran `git config --global commit.template ~/.commitmessage`, so now if I run `git commit`, it fires `vim` with this buffer:

```
#
# If applied, this commit will...

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
```

That's awesome, but if I run `git commit --amend`, I get the standard commit template:

```
My previous commit message

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# Date:      Thu Feb 8 08:55:13 2018 -0300
#
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# No changes
```

**How can I make it show the `commit.template` when amending?**

I'd expect to see both my previous commit message **plus** my template -
 something like:

```
My previous commit message

#
# If applied, this commit will...

# Please enter the commit message for your changes. Lines starting
# with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts the commit.
#
# Date:      Thu Feb 8 08:55:13 2018 -0300
#
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# No changes
```

Comment: Do you mean show template *instead of* previous commit message or *in addition to* previous commit message?

Comment: Sorry about that - in addition. I've amended the post to address that - irony, huh? Thanks for the question 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[man git-config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-committemplate) says, that's intended behaviour:

> commit.template
>
> Specify the pathname of a file to use as the template for **new** commit messages.

And looking at implementation confirms it (file `builtin/commit.c`, function `prepare_to_commit`, acting on variable `template_file` happens only if `use_message` handling did not happen earlier).

That being said - I think it may be reasonable to extend this behaviour and I bet Git maintainers wouldn't object. My first approach would be to add new config option `commit.statustemplate`, which works almost the same as `commit.template` except prepends (commented-out) message to new AND old messages.

Comment: Does `commit.statustemplate` exist in recent git version?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to "undo" the most recent commit using `git reset HEAD~1`, then doing a regular `git commit` to commit again.  This will use the template as it's a fresh commit--your old commit message will not appear in the editor.

Comment: Good workaround, but do you know why the OP’s issue is happening?

Comment: That implies loosing the previous commit's message - I get that's as closer as it gets, but it really doesn't work :/ Thanks for the suggestion, though - it may work for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this question recently, and came up with an **ugly** alias that gets the desired behaviour:

```
[alias]
  gitrocks = !test $(git rev-list --count --all) -gt 1 && git show --format="%B" --no-patch > ~/.lmao && eval cat $(git config --get commit.template) >> ~/.lmao && git reset --soft HEAD~1 && git commit -t ~/.lmao --allow-empty-message && rm ~/.lmao
```

1. Checks that you have more than 1 commit in the history (so we can reset HEAD~1)
2. Extracts the **commit message** from the commit you want to amend
3. Appends the template to the previously extracted commit message (eval is needed if your template uses `~`. If you use a full path to specify your template path you can remove it.
4. Does a `git reset --soft` and uses as template your previous commit + your actual template. `allow-empty-message` might be useful if for some reason you don't change anything, otherwise you will get an error saying you haven't changed anything and lose the commit
5. Cleanup the temporal file we used as template

Sharing just in case someone finds it useful.